How to add item to kendoListView
I have got an issue where an existing code is not adding an item to the kendoListView. Below code is basically intended to move selected items from SomeData to the SelectedData (datasource)
$('#add-something').on("click", function () {
            var items = SomeData.select();
            $.each(items, function (idx, elem) {
                var obj = $("div[id='" + $(elem).attr('id') + "']")[0];
                SelectedDS.add({
                    text: $(obj).html(),
                    id: $(obj).attr('id'),
                }
                );
                SomeData.remove($(elem));                
            });
        });

Here is how SelectedDS is defined as Kendo data source:
var SelectedDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({});

And here is how SelectedDS is bound to the SelectedData (a KendoListView):
    var SelectedData = $('#selected-list').kendoListView({
        dataSource: SelectedDS,
        selectable: "multiple",
        template: '<div class="item-selected" id="#: id #">#: text #</div>'
    }).data("kendoListView");
    SelectedDS.sort({ field: "text", dir: "desc" });

I have already debugged the code. Execution gets passed to SomeData.remove(..) statement where I had set the breakpoint

SelectedDS.total() shows incremental count in the watch but nothing
appears in SelectedData (kendoListView)
The .html() and .attr('id') returns proper text values in the watch window
The code executes in the console window without returning any exception

Update 1
SelectedData.dataSource.total() also shows the incremental count everytime the code runs.
Please help.

Due to removing contents from selected-list div at some other place in the script file, the KendoListView object was disconnected from its data source after being initialized. Adding items to it's data source then was not updating the KendoListView itself.
I changed following line and the issue got resolved.
SelectedDS.data([]); // $('#selected-list').html(' ');
